# PivotTable fields collapsed by default

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, ssas

Is it possible to have all the fields not collapsed by default?

The customer has complained that they need to un-collapse each field when opening the PivotTable.

Comment: What client tool are you using? Excel? What version?

Answer (score 0):

You can click pivot table, then click Options in menu and then click "Buttons +/-" to disable them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, doesnt seem to de-colapse all the fields though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in VBA script. For example you could write something like that (not the best solution but it's working):

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim pf As PivotField
    For Each pf In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields
        pf.DrilledDown = True
    Next pf
End Sub
```